# GPathResult field namesapceTagHints has type Map<String, String> but getClass() returns NodeChildren

Tags: groovy, types, xmlslurper

I think I am going mad. I am using Groovy for handling xml files and wanted to write a little helper class to help myself get nodes by name in a typed way. While doing this I created a class extending NodeChild:

```
class XmlNode extends NodeChild {

    XmlNode(NodeChild nodeChild) {
        super(nodeChild[0] as Node, nodeChild.parent, nodeChild.namespacePrefix, nodeChild.namespaceTagHints)
    }

    // helpful methods
}
```

But I can't instantiate this class without getting this error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '' with class 'groovy.xml.slurpersupport.NodeChildren' to class 'java.util.Map'
```

So I just had to check. Apparently:

```
println(nodeChild.namespaceTagHints.getClass())
```

returns:

```
class groovy.xml.slurpersupport.NodeChildren
```

But namespaceTagHints is supposed to be of type `Map<String, String>` at least according to the [Apache Groovy GitHub project](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-xml/src/main/java/groovy/xml/slurpersupport/GPathResult.java#L56C59-L56C59).

Can anyone explain what is going on? Or am I just completely missing something?

Comment: It's going through `getProperty`... https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-xml/src/main/java/groovy/xml/slurpersupport/GPathResult.java#L118

Comment: have you tried using `getNamespaceTagHints()` instead?

Comment: @tim_yates ah, of course! Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @cfrick `getNamespaceTagHints()` does not exist sadly. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @tim_yates mentioned `nodeChild.namespaceTagHints` evaluated through `nodeChild.getProperty("namespaceTagHints")`

and according to the code it tries to get child xml nodes with corresponding name
[GPathResult.java#L118](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/57535f7b3be4f854f69ed2790c7cd59b192c1adb/subprojects/groovy-xml/src/main/java/groovy/xml/slurpersupport/GPathResult.java#L118)

as workaround instead of `nodeChild.namespaceTagHints` you can use:

```
NodeChild.metaClass.getProperty(nodeChild, 'namespaceTagHints')
```

same for `nodeChild.parent` and  `nodeChild.namespacePrefix`